# Validating input based on array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to validate an input so that it doesn't contain a string that also appears in a given array of strings.

To explain it using a simple example, the validation should fail when I type **town**, **city** or **house**. If there is any other string, it should pass.

```
<input type="text" ng-not-in="r.arr" ...

r.arr = ["town", "city", "house"]
```

I am aware of possibilities such as using $watch, writing my own directive or ng-pattern (well, for this case it's not suitable) however, is there something built in that would do this? If not, which approach should I choose, which is the "cleanest"?

Thanks

Comment: using ng-change directive, call a method and pass the value. You can compare there and  do you stuff based on that.

Comment: If you want it tied into the form validation you need to use a directive with a custom `ngModel` validator in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ui-validate from Angular UI](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html). That way you don't have to write an own directive everytime, but simply use an expression (See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoeni/dzhfdqxm/)):

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="mod.text" ui-validate="'list.indexOf($value)==-1'">
```